# Is it useful to use stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

This is kind of a meta-question and sorry if someone already asked this: What do you think? Is it useful to ask questions on stackoverflow or would it be better to search for the answer by yourself?

My point is, for searching an appropriate answer on programming questions it would take me for example two hours. Posting the same question here takes 10min but I did not invest time for researching. Do you think this time spend on research would be time spend wisely?

Answer (score 7):

> Do you think this time spend on
>   research would be time spend wisely?

YES

> searching an appropriate answer on
>   programming questions it would take me
>   for example two hours

Why so long? Stackoverflow has great search tools and the related questions over here ----------------> makes it easy to read a cluster of similar threads.

I find the best strategy is to spend 10 minutes searching BEFORE even considering posting, I find the answer 9 times out of 10 these days.

Answer (score 2):

> My point is, for searching an appropriate answer on programming questions it would take me for example two hours.

Then, you need to learn how to search.  With practice, your ability to search will get better, and you'll find your answers quicker.

Some of my Stack Overflow answers have come from my searching the Internet and giving the answer I've found.

Of course, after you've searched a while, with no answer, then you can ask a more pointed question, because you can tell us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that some of the best answers for questions I'm researching come up on Stackoverflow. Even when I do Google searches often one (or more) of the most interesting results will be on Stackoverflow.

Stackoverflow answers will also often have links to blogs or other pages that discuss the topic in depth. Stackoverflow is research on steroids. That said I would still do a search on your favorite search engine to see if there are other perspectives not covered on Stackoverflow (and of course if you can't find an answer here).

Stackoverflow is building a good quality random knowledge base of answers to questions people have asked.